# changing the size of an icon in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I made a button using GUI PyQt5

```
    button1 = QPushButton("  Encrypt", self)
    button1.move(380,350)
    button1.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("enc.png"))
    button1.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Times', 11))
    button1.clicked.connect(self.Button1)
    button1.setGeometry(380, 350, 100, 30)
```

The problem is that i have tried many ways to change the size of the icon i uploaded which is "enc.png" but the code always give me errors

Comment: Do you want to change the size of the icon displayed on a button? Have you tried using [`setIconSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#iconSize-prop)?

Comment: yes that's what i want